# display product features in groups

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'm new to prestashop i want to display my product features in groups. like shown below

**OUTPUT**

light source :

color        :

**MECHANICAL**

Tempreture   :

weight       :

height       :

**ELECTRICAL**

input voltage :

power consumption :

```
  here output, mechanical, electricals are groups. light source, color, weight's are features of that groups.
```

please help me for this problem..

Answer (score 2):

At some point or another you will have to modify Product page template (I assume you want to display categorized features in product page).

You could create a module for categorozing features, but then you'd still have to modify product template;

The most straightforward way would be to hard-code the categories into `product.tpl`:

```
{if $feature.id == 1}
...
{elseif $feature.id == 2}
...
{/if}
```

However, I don't recommend this. THe better way would be to create a simple module in which you would prepare categorized feature for your product page:

```
public function hookDisplayFooterProduct {
  // pick ane product page hook, not necessarilly displayFooterProduct;

  $categorized_features = array(
     'electrical' => array(),
     'mechanical' => array(),
     'other'      => array(),
  );
  foreach($product->features as $f)
  {
     switch ($f->name)
     {
        case 'inpu voltage':
           $categorized_features['electrical'][] = $f;
           break;
        ....
        default:
           $categorized_features['other'][] = $f;
     }
  }

}

$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
   'categorized_features' => $categorized_features,
));
```

Then modify `product.tpl`

```
{foreach $$categorized_features as $cf}
 {$f->name}: {$f->value}
{/foreach}
```

Bear in mind that this example just displays the idea.